# Webpack configure output chunks

Tags: webpack-2

I need to get webpack dll chunks to be referenced by an absolute url. ie instead of being /[chunk].js they need to be ./content/clientlib/fstd/[chunk].js ? Anyone know how i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You might set a custom webpack output directory with [output.path](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-path) config:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/content/clientlib/fstd',
    chunkFilename: '[chunk].js',
    // ...
}
```